# android - How to detect application being activated

Tags: java, android

When the app is launched, Application `onCreate` is called. How to detect when the app is brought to front from running in background?

Comment: I would suggest taking some time and extensively reading through an [Activity's Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for `onResume()` method. Its is always called when your app comes foreground.

As per [google docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> The foreground lifetime of an activity happens between a call to
> onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). During this time
> the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with
> the user. An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused
> states -- for example when the device goes to sleep, when an activity
> result is delivered, when a new intent is delivered -- so the code in
> these methods should be fairly lightweight.

CODE SAMPLE:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("tag", "This screen is back");
}
```

Comment: I have many activities in my app. Do I have to add the onResume methods in all of them in order to detect application brought to front?

Comment: i'm afraid yes, you have to. Unless you create an abstract class which extends Activity class and then make your current activity classes to extend that base (abstract) class. By this, you can put your desired code in your base class which will be common for all your activities

Comment: Yes, I know it is possible. I thought some of some easie way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can override onResume().

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    Log.d("tag", "This screen is back");
}
```

However, I would agree with the comment that you probably should look more into this to see how Android works.